# Python POST File To PHP

Tags: php, python, post, urllib2, multipartform-data

I have a PHP with jQuery and jqGrd web application; one of the features of the application is the ability to upload files (on the client side this is handled by jqGrid) and insert the contents into a database.  This all works.  My problem is I also need to provide a command-line mechanism for manual (or automated) file uploads.  So I have the following Python code.  The code successfully logs into my API and I can see my POST data in PHP but I'm doing something wrong handling the file.

I need to POST the file in the same way it would be via the web interface... which results in PHP's $_FILES being populated.  With my code below $_FILES is empty though.  Not sure what I'm missing.

```
import base64
import cookielib
import getopt
import os
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import MultipartPostHandler

...code to process command line args, log into api, get sessionId...

#
# import
#
opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
headers = {'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=' + sessionId}

params = {
    'action': 'import', 
    'import': 'api', 
    'file': sourceFile, 
    'data': base64.b64encode(open(sourceFile, "rb").read()), 
    'id': id
}

urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler))
response = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(api, params, headers))

print response.read()
```

Probably important to know that sourceFile is simply a string supplied on the command-line; it is not the file itself.  I think this is the problem.  I am sending the filename string in params['name'] and its *contents* in params['data'].  How do I send the file as if interactively submitting it from a web form and have it in params['file']?  Is this what I need to do?

=== EDIT ===
I can't use any modules but what I have imported.  Thanks for alternate suggestions such as Requests though.

Comment: I think you don't need to specify data. try
params = {'id':'id','file':open(sourceFile, 'rb')}

Comment: Then there will be no data.  Again, sourceFile is a string - not the file itself (not a file object).

Comment: personaly i would use https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests instead of urllib2

Comment: I had tried setting param['file'] to open(sourceFile, "rb") and that didn't work.

Comment: @user1801810 : sourceFile is the file path, isn't it ? then open(sourceFile,'rb') would create a file object

Comment: sourceFile is a string... 'test.txt', for example.

Comment: Can't use any modules but what I have imported otherwise I would use Requests.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, my mistake!  Big difference between open(...) and open(...).read()!!!  Works now.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pixou post your solution as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to specify data in the params, but just give a file object. try

```
params = {
    'id':'id',
    'file':open(sourceFile, 'rb')
}
```